# sqlite3 db is empty after onCreate + adding some rows

Tags: android, sqlite

I have sqlite db for my app and this is the onCreate code

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE ...");

        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE ...");

        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE ...");
    }
```

In the first execution, the above code was executed and I even added some rows. The second execution didn't execute the above code (as expected) and I inserted some more rows.

When I go to adb shell and sqlite3 dbname.db and query for the tables (.tables) I get an empty list. When I select from one of the tables, it tells me the table does not exist and eventually I pulled the db locally and its size is 0b. What am I missing?

Comment: Please tell me you have shortened the SQL statements: Otherwise they are invalid and that is the reason they aren't created at all

Comment: I shortened them ofcourse just for this question. I don't get any exceptions whatsoever and all 3 commands were executed

Comment: Apparently, you did not get the file that the app is actually using.

Comment: funny, there is dbname.db under /data/data/com.package.name but it is NOT the db. under databases folder there is dbname (without extension) and that is the actual db.